# split string in one liner in bash or ksh or perl

Tags: regex, bash, perl, ksh

```
var="valueA valueB"
```

I want to split above string as shown below and want to read those value in one liner on bash shell.

Following script not working .

```
echo $var |awk '{print $1  $2}' |while read var; do echo  var1=$1 and var2=$2;done 

echo $var |awk '{ var1=$1 ; var2=$2}' |while read var1 var2; do echo  var1=$var1 and var2=$var2;done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ksh93, this will work of the shelf:

```
echo "$var" |
    read var1 var2 &&
        echo $var1 --- $var2
```

Effectively the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855720/667820, but the values of $var1 and $var2 are preserved.

For bash, you need bash 4.x and some options need to be (un)set.

Answer (score 4):

To get those value into `var1` and `var2`, use:

```
read var1 var2 <<<"$var"
```

The above uses a here-string and should work under bash, ksh, or zsh.

The above assumes, by default, that the two values are separated by whitespace.   Other separators are possible just by changing the value of the shell's `IFS` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
$ read -a foo <<< "$var"
$ set | grep ^foo
foo=([0]="valueA" [1]="valueB")
$ echo "${foo[1]}"
valueB
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

```
var="valueA valueB"
echo $var |while read var1 var2 ;do  echo $var1 ---- $var2;done
```

Output will be:

```
valueA --- valueB
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really work. The var1 and var2 is only visible within the while block cause that is in a subshell.

Comment: The loop is not needed.  You can use `echo $var | (read var1 var2 && echo $var1 ---- $var2)` with the same disadvantages as the loop.